# Download large files using Swagger UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I have added a GET download/{fileName} to download "tar.gz" files from Swagger UI.
The tar file is on the server and the file should be downloadable via the browser.

I have tried

```
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');

            res.download(filePath, (downloadError) => {
                // Error handling
            });
```

and also

```
          res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + fileName
          });
          fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
```

This works for small size files, but when files are more than 500MB it takes very long mostly failing the request.
The expected size of the files is always above 1GB.

How do we handle such large files that will display a download link on Swagger efficiently?

Comment: It seems like it is a request timeout issue. Can you increase the request timeout limit of swagger ui?

Comment: Tried it with req.setTimeout(0) for a 1.5 GB file. Took 20 long minutes and still no o/p. Did not wait longer than that.

Comment: Consider also asking this question in the Swagger UI repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Comment: Have added this question at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6206

Comment: For those looking for a solution, a workaround is mentioned here https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6202#issuecomment-654750277